# How do I get CiviXero to process contributions missed in the first run?

Tags: civixero

I've got the first 10 items for CiviXero transferred and it is transferring any new invoices. I set the start date to the start of the month but it does not seem to be  adding the items missed in the first run after the first 10 items.

- How do I get CiviXero to add a specific contribution to it's account_invoice table for consideration?
- How do I get CiviXero to process a specific contribution. I've tried invoice push job with contribution_id as the argument. Without the item being in account_invoice it doesn't consider it as needing being pushed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I get CiviXero to add a specific contribution to it's account_invoice table for consideration?

I think if you just edit and save the contribution, it should be added to this table (provided it does not end up with any error).

> How do I get CiviXero to process a specific contribution. I've tried invoice push job with contribution_id as the argument. Without the item being in account_invoice it doesn't consider it as needing being pushed.

Only the rows present in "civicrm_account_invoice" is considered by the civixero extension to push to xero. So if the contribution id is not present in this table, you need to make sure it does.

After a record is added to 'civicrm_account_invoice' table, you can use `contribution_id` param to push a single payment to xero.

Comment: Yes. Did the edit and save thing and it works. Alternatively add via API or SQL. I could get the contribution_id to process as well. plugin=xero contribution_id=5677. Setting start_date doesn't work, with the understanding that a contribution must be in account_invoice table first being the first problem.